# How to change CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey value from objective C?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have multiple accelerometer sensors and I need to update the advertisementData name (CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) of the each sensors for the first time of starting to use that sensors. What is the best way to update that from iOS (Objective-C or Swift) app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control this data from your app as this data arrives directly "as is" from the remote BLE device. In this case, this is the name of the device that you are scanning for. Have a look at this:-

- [CBAdvertisementDataLocalName Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdatalocalnamekey)
- [The Ultimate Guide to Apple's Core Bluetooth](https://punchthrough.com/core-bluetooth-basics/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)

The only way you can actually change this is if you have access to the accelerometer sensors' source code, and then changing the name will be dependent on the specific software running on these sensors.